# mumudvb starting script is not working

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have installed mumudvb manually based on instructions in here

https://github.com/braice/MuMuDVB

to get the starting scripts working i executed these commands

```
cp scripts/debian/etc/default/mumudvb /etc/default/mumudvb
cp scripts/debian/etc/init.d/mumudvb /etc/init.d/mumudvb
```

/etc/default/mumudvb :

```
#Mumudvb init config file
#
# This file is used to specify the locations of mumudvb config files for each card
#

#If you don't want to automatically start mumudvb, uncomment this line
#DONTSTARTMUMU=true

#If you want to launch a command before mumudvb (for example for automatic configuration generation)
#LAUNCH_BEFORE_MUMU=""

#Options for mumudvb
DAEMON_OPTS=""

#The user to launch mumudvb
DAEMONUSER="username"

#Change this line to reflect your configuration
#Ex : ADAPTERS="0 1 2 4"
ADAPTERS="0"

#Location of the config files
#Ex : MUMUDVB_CONF_1="/etc/mumudvb/card1.conf"
MUMUDVB_CONF_0="/etc/mumudvb/card0.conf"
```

this is the init.d/mumudvb script :

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          mumudvb
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: mumudvb
# Description:       Digital television streaming program
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/bin/mumudvb
PIDDIR=/var/run/mumudvb
DEFAULT_FILE=/etc/default/mumudvb
NAME=mumudvb
DESC="television streaming program"

#Reading of the config file
if [ -f "$DEFAULT_FILE" ] ; then
        . "$DEFAULT_FILE"
fi

if [ "$DONTSTARTMUMU" = "true" ]; then exit 0; fi

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

test -x $DAEMON || exit 5

set -e

do_start() {
        if [ ! -d $PIDDIR ]; then
                mkdir -p $PIDDIR
        fi
        chown $DAEMONUSER $PIDDIR
    if [ -x "$LAUNCH_BEFORE_MUMU" ]; then
        log_daemon_msg "Launching pre script ..."
        eval $LAUNCH_BEFORE_MUMU
        log_daemon_msg "Done."
    fi
    for ADAPTER in $ADAPTERS; do
        #Todo : fails if all card fails
        log_daemon_msg " Starting card $ADAPTER"
        eval CONFIG_FILE = MUMUDVB_CONF_0
        if [ ! -f $CONFIG_FILE ]; then
                   log_warning_msg " Card $ADAPTER: Config file $CONFIG_FILE not found."
        else
           start-stop-daemon --start --oknodo --name mumudvb_$ADAPTER\
                     --make-pidfile --pidfile=$PIDDIR/mumudvb_init_$ADTAPTER.pid\
                     --chuid $DAEMONUSER --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS --card $ADAPTER -c $CONFIG_FILE
        fi
    done
}

do_stop() {
    for PIDFILE in `ls $PIDDIR/mumudvb_init_*.pid 2> /dev/null`; do
            start-stop-daemon --stop --oknodo --pidfile "$PIDFILE" \
                    --exec $DAEMON
    done
}

case "$1" in
  start)
        if [ ! -f "$DEFAULT_FILE" ]; then
                log_failure_msg "$DEFAULT_FILE not found, Can't start $NAME"
                exit 6
        fi

        log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC: $NAME"
        do_start
        log_end_msg $?
        ;;
  stop)
        log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC: $NAME"
        do_stop
        log_end_msg $?
        ;;
  restart|force-reload)
        log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC: $NAME"
        do_stop
        sleep 1
        do_start
        log_end_msg $?
        ;;
  status)
        status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$DESC: $NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
  *)
        log_success_msg "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

when i run :

```
sudo service mumudvb status
or
sudo service mumudvb start
```

nothing returns ...
shouldn't it at least return an error or something ?

**note: runing

> mumudvb -c /etc/mumudvb/card0.conf

works fine**

Comment: did you install mumudvb 2.0 without any bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the file `/etc/default/mumudvb` set `DONTSTARTMUMU` to `false`

```
DONTSTARTMUMU=false
```